# Pandas dataframe not creating properly

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excelfile whose contents looks like below,

```
        this is is the line we want to ignore
        id        name           dept               deptid
        2         abc                 it                   1
        3         xyz                 mech            2
        1         mno               stats             3
```

Please note that the first 2 rows I need to skip.first one is a line and second one is header.

I am using below command,

```
      import pandas as pd
      pd.read_excel(my file, sheet_name=1, skip_rows=[ i for i in range(2)])
```

Everything is fine with the output,except that it converts the first value of Deptid column which is 1 to 1.1

If I give any other number its working fine.

Please suggest why it's happening.

Comment: @anky_91: The docs say `skiprows` is list-like.  So `[0,1]` is appropriate according to the official docs.

Comment: I need to skip both first and 2 rows.

Comment: @Damon , as the previous comment by @john suggests , you can use `skiprows=[0,1]`

Comment: @Damon use `skiprows` instead of `skip_rows` .

Comment: Please post the file so we can try it.

Comment: try `pd.read_excel(my file, sheet_name=1, header=[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in Excel.  I bet the actual value in the first cell for `deptid` is 1.1, but you have some formatting applied which prevents display of decimal digits.  So the data really is 1.1, even if Excel doesn't show it that way.  You'll see when you open the file and click on the cell, then look in the edit bar for what text is really there.

Comment: I have done that as well. Also I deleted that value and again put 1 there.But it's not working. Also strange thing is if I put any other number in that cell other than 1 it works fine.